# Environment variable in Spring property file

Tags: spring, properties, environment-variables

I'm trying to use an environment variable inside a Spring property file but it doesn't seem to work

where the app is running

```
export TEST_VAR=hello
```

myapp.properties

```
test.variable=${TEST_VAR}
enter code here
```

But when I test, the test.variable doesn't translate to hello but stays ${TEST_VAR}.

How can I get Env variable from within that file?

I load the property file this way

```
<bean id="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="singleton" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:myapp.properties</value>
        <value>file://#{systemProperties['myApp.configurationFile']}</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="props" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="props" />
  </bean>
```

myApp.configurationFile is a system variable I pass when tomcat starts up through -DmyApp.configurationFile=...

Comment: In the way of doing, I don't see any noticeable issue. You should  provide a MCVE : a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is literally the only thing I do minus the way I instruct spring how to,oad the property file. I have added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the configure place holder fixed my issue

```
<property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
```